# Percantage of rows with same key in from total amount of rows table

Tags: mysql, sql, having

I need to find the percentage of logs in my table that are duplicated. Therefore I did a query with a "having" that checks if the key was duplicated. The problem is that after doing this "having" I lost all the logs that were not duplicated.

Here is the table:

[image]

Here is my query:

```
(SELECT count(params_advertiserId) AS duplicates 
 FROM android_clicks 
 GROUP BY params_advertiserId ,app_id ,date --my key is a triplet
 HAVING COUNT(params_advertiserId) > 1)
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It this what you want?

```
select (count(*) - count(distinct params_advertiserId, app_id, date)) / count(*) as duplicate_ratio
from android_clicks ac;
```

Your query is incorrect because `AND` is used for boolean expressions.  So the result of the `GROUP BY` expression is true, false, or `NULL`.

If you want the count, then wrap it as a subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as num_duplicates
FROM (SELECT params_advertiserId, app_id, date AS duplicates 
      FROM android_clicks ac
      GROUP BY params_advertiserId, app_id, date 
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
     );
```

Comment: Thanks! I was stuborn to find the exact rows and then give the ratio, and you did it the correct way! I have no way to check it but I think this is the correct way! Also I took in your comment regarding the "AND"

Answer (score 1):

`GROUP BY` use comma `,` instead of `AND`

```
 SELECT count(params_advertiserId) AS duplicates 
 FROM android_clicks 
 GROUP BY params_advertiserId , app_id , date
 HAVING COUNT(params_advertiserId) > 1
```